# Criterion of map $M_f\to Z$ to be continuous

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I was about to prove the following proposition

> A map $M_f\to Z$ is continuous if and only if the induced maps $X\times I\to Z$ and $Y\to Z$ are both continuous.

Here, $M_f$ is a mapping cylinder of $f:X\to Y$ i.e. $M_f = X\times I\sqcup Y/f(x)\sim (x,0)$ for $x\in X$. I first let $p:X\to X\times I$ by $x\mapsto (x,0)$. Letting $f_1:X\times I\to M_f$ and $f_2:Y\to M_f$ be induced map by inclusion, I considered the following diagram:

[image: dd]

If $g$ is continuous, then clearly $i_1,i_2$ are continuous. To see the converse, first see the following diagram:

[image]

It's a bit complicated but readable. The upper half is a universal property of disjoint union and $q$ is a quotient map. Now, I want to show $g\circ q \equiv \tilde{f}$. Let $x\in M_f$. If $x\in X\times I$, then $g\circ q(x) =g\circ q\circ j_1(x) = g\circ f_1(x) = i_1(x)= \tilde{f}\circ j_1(x) = \tilde{f}(x)$. Similarly to $x\in Y$. Now the following fact:

> The surjection $f:X\to Y$ is an identification map if and only if for any function $g:Y\to Z$, $g\circ f$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is continuous.

Hence, $g$ is continuous.

Is this a valid proof?

Note. I don't know anything about Category theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Trust yourself!

Note that the mapping cylinder is constructed as the *pushout* of the pair of maps $(f,p)$ which is a general concept of category theory. It would be worth to learn same basic category theory to understand that point.

Anyway, you do need that. As you said, we have a quotient map $q : (X \times I) \sqcup Y \to M_f$. The universal property of the quotient shows then that $g : M_f \to Z$ is continuous iff $g \circ q$ is continuous. But $g \circ q$ lives on the disjoint union of $X \times I$ and $Y$, thus it is continuous iff $g \circ q \circ j_1 = q \circ f_1$ and $g \circ q \circ j_2 = q \circ f_2$ are continuous.

Comment: In Bredon's textbook, he said 'the proof is an easy application of the definition of the quotient topology on a mapping cylinder' but I think it's not very easy